# Is there a way NOT to capture $this in a PHP anonymous function?

Tags: php, closures, this, anonymous-function

I have a PHP code that looks like this:

```
class A {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->b = new B(function($x) { return $x + 1; });
    }
};

class B {
    public function __construct($dataProcessingFunction) {
        $this->dataProcessingFunction = $dataProcessingFunction;
    }

    public function processData($data) {
        $f = $this->dataProcessingFunction;
        return $f($data);
    }
};
```

But there is a problem: I absolutely need B's destructor to be called before A's destructor. This seems reasonable as you can see. The B object doesn't need any A, so there should be no problem.

But since PHP 5.4.0, closures seem to automatically capture implicitly $this. Therefore, the lambda function that I pass to B and that is stored by B contains a reference to A.

Which means that A contains a pointer to B, and B contains a pointer to A (through the closure). In this kind of situation, the PHP documentation says that destructors are only called on garbage collection and in a random order. And guess what: B's destructor is always called before A's.

Is there a way to solve this in a elegant way?

Comment: not "seem" - definitely, as pointed out in the anon func changelog: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: The most elegant way I can think of would be to alter your code so you are not dependent on a destructor order.  Relying on a specific order like this could get you in trouble.

Comment: I don't have PHP 5.4 where I am so I can't test, but try using `create_function`.  You may also be able to use the `Closure` class, or just change what the function is bound to (not so anonymous as that would require assignment, I think).

Comment: @user1161318: my code is an output filtering system. I create filter A, then filter B, then C, then D. Each filter pass its result to the next one. The destruction order should be the inverse: D should be destroyed, then C, then B, then A, so that the flushes are correct. But it's not the case because of this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Explosion Pills, I've found the solution in the [`Closure`](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.closure.php) class.

You can in fact change the `$this` stored inside the closure, like this:

```
$cb = function($x) { return $x + 1; };
$cb = $cb->bindTo(null);

// now $cb doesn't contain a pointer to $this anymore
```

Note that you can't do this, or you'll get a syntax error:

```
// syntax error
$cb = (function($x) { return $x + 1; })->bindTo(null);
```